# How to set h:panelGrid height in JSF?

Tags: html, css, jsf

In JSF, I am using panelGrid which is equivalent to table in html. How to set height=100% in it? width=100% exists but not height.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start, JSF is irrelevant here. It's now all about its generated HTML code. Open page in webbrowser, rightclick and view source. Concentrate you on *that* HTML source. That's all what CSS (and JS) can see and apply.

I assume that you mean with 100% height the full viewport height (the "visible" height). Now, to achieve full viewport height in CSS, only setting a `height: 100%` on the desired HTML element itself is not sufficient. It will be relative to its parent element, all the chain up to the `<html`> element. So if you basically have a:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>100% viewport height demo - FAIL</title>
        <style>
            .mytable { height: 100%; background: yellow; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="mytable"><tr><td>cell</td></tr></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

It will be 100% of the height of the `<body>` element. The height of the `<body>` itself is in turn relative to the height of the `<html>` element. But the both elements doesn't have a height of 100%. Copy'n'paste'n'run it. You'll see, it does not cover the full viewport.

If you want to achieve a full viewport height, then you need to apply `height: 100%` on both the `<body>` and `<html>` elements as well (you of course also need to reset the margins).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>100% viewport height demo - GOOD</title>
        <style>
            html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; }
            .mytable { height: 100%; background: yellow; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="mytable"><tr><td>cell</td></tr></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Apply this knowledge on JSF as well. The `h:panelGrid` just renders a `<table>` element. Its `styleClass` will be rendered as HTML `class` attribute.